# IE BHO c++ data sharing among tabs

Tags: c++, multithreading, internet-explorer, communication, bho

I would like the BHO instances of my IE extension to be able to share common data. I just need them to share a couple of variables, so I am trying to find an easy solution for the problem.

The alternatives I can think of, from easier to more complex are:

1) Writing/reading data to/from the file system or to the registry, see [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/PMSurvivalGuide.aspx#sampleapp). **Question**: is this information accessible from BHO instances running in different threads?

2) Developing a Windows Service or a background application that communicates with all BHO instances, see [MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/aa44ac3f-5170-47b7-8946-3fb20cb30aee/). **Problem**: I have NO IDEA how to make this, or where to start with. I am worried about the user having to install to many things.

3) Providing IPC mechanisms so that the different BHO instances can communicate directly to each other. Like using the *IGlobalInterfaceTable*, see [ookii article](http://www.ookii.org/post/ie_addon_development_communicating_with_tabs_across_threads.aspx). **Problem**: Yes, you can store pointers in this *IGlobalInterfaceTable* and get cookies to access them back, but how can you share one cookie obtained in BHO Instance 1 with BHO Instance 2, so that the second instance can access the data inserted in the *IGlobalInterfaceTable* by the first one? Aren't we having here the same data sharing problem again?

Well, as you see, after a whole week looking for a solution I simply don't know how to start dealing with this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, Memory Mapped Files are used for this purpose. It's a non-trivial amount of work, however, as you must ensure that they are ACL'd properly to allow cross-process access (each tab may be in a different process) and work across multiple integrity levels.

Comment: Boost::interprocess can make it a little easier to set up, but harder to debug.

Answer (score 1):

1 sort of, except the place a normal web site can write is [isolated from a trusted web site can access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932118).

2 Writing a service is probably the easiest way, given the abundant amount of documentation on how to write a windows service (you even get an ATL project wizard if you use Visual C++), and your broker code can survive a tab processes crash or even a user log off.

3 Indeed you have the same sharing problem again, COM messages are blocked by UIPI unless you can change the message filter, but the messages used by COM are not documented. I would use something like named pipe/memory file mapping.

You need to host the communication broker code somewhere and only create it once. You can write something like how computers in a [workgroup elect the master browser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188001) (kind of chatty), or have a broker process to do the communication work (e.g in a windows service).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think I'll go for the memory mapped files since it is closer to the shared data concept that I am looking for and I found [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/popupblocker2.aspx) which seems to be quite well explained.